# Invalid template file: 'Magehit_Bestsellerproducts::html/bestsellerblock.phtml'

Tags: module, template, magento2.2, best-seller

After upgrading to Magento 2.2.0, the Magehit bestseller module is causing  the following exception. Can someone please help solving it?

Thanks

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template
>   file: 'Magehit_Bestsellerproducts::html/bestsellerblock.phtml' in
>   module: 'Magehit_Bestsellerproducts' block's name: 'bestseller_data'
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid
>   template file:
>   'Magehit_Bestsellerproducts::html/bestsellerblock.phtml' in module:
>   'Magehit_Bestsellerproducts' block's name: 'bestseller_data'
>
> #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/generated/code/Magehit/Bestsellerproducts/Block/Home/BestsellerList/Interceptor.php(713):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView(false) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300):
>   Magehit\Bestsellerproducts\Block\Home\BestsellerList\Interceptor->fetchView(false)
>   #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/generated/code/Magehit/Bestsellerproducts/Block/Home/BestsellerList/Interceptor.php(1038):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() #4
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558):
>   Magehit\Bestsellerproducts\Block\Home\BestsellerList\Interceptor->toHtml()
>   #5
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('bestseller_data') #6
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('bestseller_data')
>   #7
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('bestseller_data')
>   #8
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('bestseller_data', true)
>   #9
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('bestseller_data')
>   #10
>   /var/www/vhosts/testdomain/staging.testdomain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')

... further errors

Comment: can you paste template path?

Comment: @BareFeet: Searching for the bestsellerblock.phtml gives me these two paths: ./var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/Magehit/Bestsellerproducts/view/frontend/templates/bestsellerblock.phtml  
./app/code/Magehit/Bestsellerproducts/view/frontend/templates/bestsellerblock.phtml

Comment: I think what Barefeet means is can you post screenshot(s) of your entire file with regards to your module, it may make debugging a bit easier

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write comments so I write this on answers.

Temporary removing Magehit/Bestsellerproducts/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml fix the problem and store work again.

I have same issue plus I found this on logs:

```
[2018-04-09 18:55:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bestsellerproducts.left' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'div.sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-04-09 18:55:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'new.link3' tries to reorder itself towards 'new-link2', but their parents are different: 'header-custom-link' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-04-09 18:55:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'new.link2' tries to reorder itself towards 'new-link', but their parents are different: 'header-custom-link' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-04-09 18:55:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bestsellerproducts.left' element cannot be added as child to 'div.sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-04-09 18:55:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-04-09 18:55:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-04-09 18:55:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-04-09 18:55:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-04-09 18:55:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-04-09 18:55:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bestsellerproducts.left' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'div.sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
```

This is bestsellerblock.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

?>
<?php
$enableModule = $block->getSectionStatus();
if($this->getSlideAuto() == 1) $slide_auto = 'true'; else $slide_auto = 'false';
if($this->getPagination() == 1) $slide_pagination = 'true'; else $slide_pagination = 'false';
if($this->getNavigation() == 1) $slide_navigation = 'true'; else $slide_navigation = 'false';
if ($enableModule) {
    $block_title = $block->getPageTitle();
    $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $imageBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image');
    ?>
    <?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
        <div class="message info empty"><div><?php echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php
        if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
            $viewMode = 'grid';
            $image = 'category_page_grid';
            $showDescription = false;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        } else {
            $viewMode = 'list';
            $image = 'category_page_list';
            $showDescription = true;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
        }
        $pos = $block->getPositioned();
        $position = '';
        if ($pos != null) {
            $position = ' style="left:' . $block->getVar("{$image}:width") . 'px;'
                    . 'top:' . $block->getVar("{$image}:height") . 'px;"';
        }
        ?>
        <div class="pad-main-bottom wrapper <?php echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php echo $viewMode; ?>">
            <div class="block-title-main">
                <h2><?php echo $block_title ?></h2>
                <div class="title-border"></div>
            </div>
            <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
            <ol class="products list items product-items bestsellerproducts">
                <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
                <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                    <?php echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li style="margin-top:20px;" class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li style="margin-top:20px;" class="item product product-item">' ?>
                    <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                        <?php // Product Image    ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                            <span style="width:240px;" class="product-image-container">
                                <span style="padding-bottom: 137%;" class="product-image-wrapper">
                                    <?php
                                    $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                                            ->init($_product, 'product_page_image_large')
                                            ->constrainOnly(FALSE)
                                            ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                            ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                            ->resize(270, 371)
                                            ->getUrl();
                                    ?>
                                    <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" />
                                    <!--<img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php //echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($_product, 'image');                          ?>"height="240" width="240" />-->
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </a>

                        <div class="product details product-item-details">
                            <div style="padding: 0 2px;"><?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?></div>
                            <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                            ?>
                            <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                <a class="product-item-link"
                                   href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                       <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                                </a>
                            </strong>
                            <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
                            <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                            <div class="">
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                    <div class="actions-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                            <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                            <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                        title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                        class="action tocart primary">
                                                    <span><?php echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                <div class="stock available"><span><?php echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()): ?>
                                            <a href="#"
                                               class="action towishlist"
                                               title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               data-post='<?php echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                               data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                               role="button">
                                                <span><?php echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                            </a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php
                                        $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');
                                        ?>
                                        <a href="#"
                                           class="action tocompare"
                                           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                           aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                           data-post='<?php echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                           role="button">
                                            <span><?php echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php if ($showDescription): ?>
                                    <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                           class="action more"><?php echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
            <div class="view-all"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('bestsellerproducts') ?>"><?php echo __('View all') ?></a></div>
        </div>
        <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {}
                }
                }
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'cpowlcarousel'], function () {
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery(".bestsellerproducts").owlCarousel({
                    items: 5,
                    itemsDesktop: [1080, 4],
                    itemsDesktopSmall: [860, 4],
                    itemsTablet: [768,3],
                    itemsTabletSmall: [639, 2],
                    itemsMobile: [360, 1],
                    pagination: <?php echo $slide_pagination ?>,
                    navigation: <?php echo $slide_navigation ?>,
                    lazyLoad : true,
                    navigationText: ["<div class='prev-btn'>previours</div>", "<div class='next-btn'>next</div>"],
                    autoPlay : <?php echo $slide_auto ?>,
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change cms_index_index.xml like bellow:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magehit_Bestsellerproducts::css/bestsellerproducts.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magehit\Bestsellerproducts\Block\Home\BestsellerList" name="bestseller_data" template="Magehit_Bestsellerproducts::bestsellerblock.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```